# How to get vendor details from order inside woocommerce hooks - Dokan

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, dokan

How can I get vendor info/details from an order inside woocommerce hooks. So far I've been able to get standard woocommerce fields from the order like so:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'wc_send_complete_notif');
function wc_send_complete_notif( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $phone = $order->billing_phone;
}
```

Now what I want to do is get `Vendor Name` and `Vendor Phone Number` from that order and do some post processing.

Comment: I have the same doubt, were you able to achieve it?

Comment: Are you using Dokan?

Comment: Yes, and I found the solution to this question I have added an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dokan has a helper function to get the seller id by order. Here's how to get vendor user ID from an order:

```
$seller = dokan_get_seller_id_by_order( $order_id );
```

Now, in case you are working with sub-orders:

```
        $sellers = dokan_get_seller_id_by_order( $order_id );

        // check has sub order 
        if ( $order->get_meta('has_sub_order') ) {
            foreach ($sellers as $seller) {
                $seller_info      = get_userdata( $seller );
                $seller_email     = $seller_info->user_email;
            }
        } else {
            $seller_info      = get_userdata( $sellers );
            $seller_email     = $seller_info->user_email;
        }
```

It is tested and working with the latest Dokan version 3.x

Comment: If Order has suborder, this method (dokan_get_seller_id_by_order) will return 0

Answer (score 0):

```
//If there is a suborder, the relevant method returns 0
if(!dokan_get_seller_id_by_order( $order_id )):
    //get seller id with sub_orders
    $sub_orders = get_children( array( 'post_parent' => $order_id, 'post_type' => 'shop_order' ) );
    foreach($sub_orders as $sub_order):
        $seller_id[] = dokan_get_seller_id_by_order( $sub_order->ID );
    endforeach;
else:
    $seller_id =  dokan_get_seller_id_by_order( $order_id );
endif;
```